# If ofbiz a good enough ERP to use for Human Resources module?

Tags: java, apache, frameworks, ofbiz

So I've been assigned the task of learning Apache Ofbiz ERP and give a report weather my company should continue working with it. So far I've only seen errors, incomplete functionalities and missing functions.

Should I continue ?
Is it worth spending time on ?

Comment: ```I've been assigned the task of learning Apache Ofbiz ERP``` - You have been assigned the task to evaluate a tool so learn about it and see if that fits with your requirements or not and based on that share your recommendation to your company

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out Scipio ERP as well - it is a more modern variant of the OFBiz project with greatly improved applications, better development features and more.